# Where can I find my pg_hba.conf file (for django app on a2hosting)

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, web-deployment

I'm deploying my first ever website (it's a Python 3.7, Django 2.2.9 site on a2hosting) and I'm getting the following error when trying to run migrations.

```sh
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xx.xx.xxx.xx", user "xxxxxx", database "xxxxxx", SSL off
```

Googling around, I've gathered that I have to add an entry in the `pg_hba.conf` file for the particular user.

Problem is this is my first experience with Linux, and I can't seem to locate the `pg_hba.conf` file to test this solution.

Please, where can I find this file (relative to my approot)?

**PS: I've successfully installed Postgresql and SSL for the site.**

Comment: Check out this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/256711/8

Comment: How did you install postgres and on which linux distribution?

Comment: @JimJones I've been on a break in a place without internet connection. I'll look into your answer asap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Considering you have access to the database locally, just execute `SHOW hba_file;` using a client of your choice to see where your `pg_hba.conf` file is located.

```
SHOW hba_file;

              hba_file               
-------------------------------------
 /etc/postgresql/11/main/pg_hba.conf
(1 Zeile)
```

If you feel curious about other paths and variables, take a look at `SHOW ALL;` ;-)

Comment: This worked for me. However, it pointed me to a place where I don't have write permissions. I just have to figure out how to get the permission, and I'll be good to go.

Comment: @tommygallaher if you don't have `sudo` permissions you'll have to find someone who does :) Changes in the `pg_hba.conf` file requires either a database restart or a reload via `SELECT pg_reload_conf();` Good luck!